# Recursive Relationship with a Description in Django Models

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

My project involves sorting many images. As part of this sorting, I want to be able to manually (as the user) mark several images as duplicates of each other with a brief description of why each relationship was created. These relationships will not be defined at the time an image is loaded into Django, but at a later time after uploading all the images.

My question: How can I create an unlimited number of `duplicates`? Aka, how would I define that *several* images are all related to each other, *and* include a `CharField` description of why each relationship exists?

This is a django app and the code is from `models.py`.

Thank you.

```
from django.db import models

class tag(models.Model):
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    x = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    y = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    point = [x,y]
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.tag

#...

class image(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='directory/')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True, help_text="Descriptive image title")
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(tag, blank=True, help_text="Searchable Keywords")
    #...

    ##### HELP NEEDED HERE ##################
    duplicates = [models.ManyToManyField('self', null=True), models.CharField(max_length=60)]
    ##########################################
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.image.name
```

Comment: Sounds like something you would use a many-to-many relationship with. You can also set a custom 'through' model allowing you to add fields like a description. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to go with an extra model for grouping those duplicates, because you want a description field with it. Something like

```
class DupeSeries(Model):
    description = CharField(...)
    members = ManyToManyField("image", related_name="dupes", ...)
```

Example usage:

```
img = image(title="foo!", image="/path/to/image.jpg")
dup_of_img = image(title="foo!dup", image="/path/to/dup/image.jpg")
img.save()
dup_of_img.save()

dupes_of_foo = DupeSeries(description="foo! lookalikes")
dupes_of_foo.members.add(img, dup_of_img)

# Notice how *img.dupes.all()* returns both image instances.
assert(list(img.dupes.all()) == [img, dup_of_img])
```

Comment: Since I am very new at this, can you explain how this would link two images together, and whether this would allow me to call `image.duplicates` to list all other related images? You may be suggesting a better way but I'm not quite catching on...

Comment: aka, it seems like you are suggesting this (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships), but I don't really understand where you're going with that.

Comment: Please check out my edit. I think this is easier to use and understand than the solution with 'through', but if you need it, I could edit to showcase the 'through' method as well.